# Anyone have experience using Sprotty with Theia?

Tags: eclipse, modeling, theia

I have successfully created my LSP using Xtext and have integrated it with Theia. As for the archived repo, I was referring to the theia-ide/theia-sprotty-example: https://github.com/theia-ide/theia-sprotty-example

The directory structure of my project is almost the same as the one listed here: https://github.com/theia-ide/theia-xtext

But am still a bit confused on where to begin.

First, should I add a .diagram project to my lsp, and if so, which specific files should I add? I understand that the yang-lsp repo contains some files that are specific to yang, but not sure which files are essential for integrating Sprotty.